# Does a weakly convergent sequence in $W^{1,p}(B_1)$ which also converges in $C^{0,\alpha}(B_1)$ converges strongly in $W^{1,p}(B_1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde, regularity

Given a sequence $u_k\in W^{1,p}(B_1)\cap C^{\alpha}(B_1)$ such that $\|u_k\|_{C^{\alpha}(B_1)}\le 1$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$. Suppose we have
$$
u_k \rightharpoonup u\;\;\mbox{weakly in $W^{1,p}(B_1)$}
$$
and we also have
$$
u_k \rightarrow u_0\;\;\mbox{in $C^{\alpha}(B_1)$}.
$$

Can I imply from the above two informations that $u_k\rightarrow u_0$ strongly in $W^{1,p}(B_1)$?

Comment: I don't think so. Let $f_n: [0,1] \to \mathbf{R}$ be a zig-zag function with step size $1/n$ and $\lvert f \rvert_\infty = 1/n$. Then every $f_n$ is bounded as a Lipschitz function, and the sequence converges to zero weakly in $W^{1,p}$ and strongly in $C^{0,\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$. However $\lvert f_n \rvert_{1,p} \geq 1$ for all $n$ because $f_n' = 1$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @LeoMoos Thanks for the comment, but the example you mentioned does not have a uniform bound on Holder norm. In fact the Holder norm of $f_n$ blows up as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Are you sure? The Lipschitz norm is $1 + 1/n$, so that seems strange. I have the Holder norm decaying like $n^{\alpha-1}$.

Comment: @LeoMoos Please let me know the definition of zig zag function you are considering.

Comment: I defined them in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. Define a sequence of 'zig-zag' functions $(f_n)$ on $[0,1]$ as follows. Let $f_n$ be $\frac{2}{n}$-periodic with $f_n(x) = x$ when $x \in [0,\frac{1}{n}]$ and $f_n(x) = \frac{2}{n}- x$ when $x \in [\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}]$. Every function is Lipschitz with $\lvert f_n \rvert_\infty \leq 1/n$ and $\lvert f_n' \rvert_\infty = 1$.

Moreover the sequence converges to zero weakly in $W^{1,p}$ for every $p \in (1,\infty)$ and strongly in $C^{0,\alpha}$ for every $\alpha \in (0,1)$, while $\lvert f_n \rvert_{1,p} \geq 1$ for every $n$.